# Submit form only when stripe payment is made

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I have a form and I want to submit its data only when the stripe payment has been made. The stripe payment corresponds to this JS script:

```
// Get Stripe publishable key
fetch("/config")
.then((result) => { return result.json(); })
.then((data) => {
  // Initialize Stripe.js
  const stripe = Stripe(data.publicKey);

  // new
  // Event handler
  document.querySelector("#submitBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Get Checkout Session ID
    fetch("/create-checkout-session")
    .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      // Redirect to Stripe Checkout
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: data.sessionId})
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  });
document.getElementById("form_post").submit();
});
```

What I've done so far is to add `document.getElementById("form_post").submit();` at the end of the JS script as you can see but it does not work. With this code, the stripe payment can be made but my form is not submitted.

Here is the HTML part with the form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/js/all.js"></script>
  <form id="form_post" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <label for="sername">Nom de l'entreprise</label>
    <input name="username" id="username" value="{{ request.form['username'] }}" required>
    </form>

    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="button is-primary" id="submitBtn">Purchase!</button>
      </div>
    </section>

{% endblock %}
```

For information, I'm using python's framework Flask.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because Stripe redirects you to another page for the checkout session, so your code after the redirect will never run unless the redirect fails because of a network issue or some other reason.

When Stripe returns you to your site, after the payment is complete, they attach a query parameter to the redirect URL you provide. You can grab that query parameter and submit it to your server to do any processing.

Anything you need to store about the user from the form you should do ahead of time before redirecting. Then validate that the payment was successful after the fact on the server side by handling the webhook that Stripe sends or by checking the status of that checkout session.

Comment: This is correct. Checkout is a redirect, so that information is lost. If you need to persist some data, you'll have to record it prior to the redirect in your system. You can pass it to your server when you create the session and either attach to the Checkout session as metadata or record in your db to be linked afterwards. In either case you should listen for `checkout.session.completed` webhooks to fulfill your orders. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. Indeed what you both said is clear in theory but I have no idea how to implement that even if I followed the stripe tutorial about webhook and added it to my routes.

Comment: No problem @Uvo. When you're starting out I would suggest looking through various tutorials and trying to improve your skills by implementing them. For instance, the entire process you're trying to do is implemented for you here on Next.js https://vercel.com/guides/getting-started-with-nextjs-typescript-stripe You can also find other tutorials online for other languages and frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but to be honest, I did not find a solution to my problem yet with it. What I've imagined so far is to add a "payment" column to the table where I store form informations in my database and when the webhook give back a successful answer about the payment, I add a value the to payment column indicating that I can use the data of this form/user. But I can't figure out how to link the user that complete the form and the same user completing the payement.